# How to add to visual studio solution a file that exists in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've deleted a file by accident. Then I created another file with the same name. When I tried to check in the change, it didn't work out and got an error. I undid the changes then deleted the file, there's no more error when I try to check in.

I'd like now to get the latest version of the file before I deleted it.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TFS, a deletion only takes effect when you check in the said deletion change, and thankfully, this operation is reversible.

Here are the most common recovery scenarios, assuming that the file already had revisions stored in TFS before the accidental deletion:

1. If the file is still visible in the Source Control Explorer and is marked for deletion (under the Pending Change column):

   Then it means that you've deleted the file from your solution (and file system), but that you didn't checked in the changes yet.

   - Use the "Undo" command of its contextual menu to restore the file in your workspace to its latest version before deletion.
   - From there, you'll be able to add the restored file to your solution.
2. If the file is still visible in the Source Control Explorer and is **not** marked for deletion:

   Then it means that you've deleted the file from your file system.

   - Use the "Get Specific Version" command of the file's contextual menu to restore it in your workspace. In the "Get" window, select "Latest Version" and enable both options.
   - From there, you'll be able to add the restored file to your solution.
3. If the file is **not** visible in the Source Control Explorer:

   Then it means that you've checked in the deletion change.

   - Turn on the "View deleted files" option of the Source Control Explorer (usually the 2nd button of its toolbar) to see your deleted file.
   - Use the "Undelete" command of the file's contextual menu to restore it in your workspace.
   - From there, you'll be able to add the restored file to your solution and you'll eventually have to check in the undeleted file to make it available to others, since this file only exists in your workspace.